# xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition

Tags: python, xml, soap, spyne

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it? I've tried to pass the type_name as Lead, but It didn't work either.

> xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap11env:Bodysoap11env:Faultsoap11env:Client.SchemaValidationError:1:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_ELT_4_2:
> Element '{http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound}sObject', attribute
> '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value
> '{urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com}Lead' of the xsi:type
> attribute does not resolve to a type
> definition.</soap11env:Fault></soap11env:Body></soap11env:Envelope>%

My Code:

```
import logging
from spyne.model.primitive import Unicode, String, Integer64
from spyne.model.complex import ComplexModel
from spyne.service import ServiceBase
from spyne.decorator import rpc

class SObjectType(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com'
    __type_name__ = 'sObject'
    Id = String
    Company_ID__C = Integer64
    Company_Size_Text__c = Unicode

class NotificationType(ComplexModel):
    Id = Unicode
    sObject = SObjectType

class notificationsType(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound'
    __type_name__ = 'notifications'
    OrganizationId = Unicode
    ActionId = Unicode
    SessionId = String(nillable="true")
    Notification = NotificationType.customize(max_occurs='100')

class SomeService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(notificationsType)
    def MyMethod(ctx, notificationsType):
        print(notificationsType)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from spyne.application import Application
    from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
    from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('listening to http://127.0.0.1:8080')

    application = Application([SomeService],
                          tns='http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound',
                          in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                          out_protocol=Soap11())

    wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8080, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This is the request:

> curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --data
> @"/home/sample_request.xml"
> "http://127.0.0.1:8080/?wsdl"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>082342234242</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>3432342DFSFDf343</ActionId>
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <Notification>
    <Id>34FG23234343irKYQAY</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Lead" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>00Q4100000vNZBlEAO</sf:Id>
     <sf:Company_ID__C>4203320</sf:Company_ID__C>
     <sf:Company_Size_Text__c>501-1,000</sf:Company_Size_Text__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
   <Notification>
    <Id>6565ffd45eewwe322323</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Lead" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>3453453453453</sf:Id>
     <sf:Company_ID__C>4556456</sf:Company_ID__C>
     <sf:Company_Size_Text__c></sf:Company_Size_Text__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Done! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes in addition to what I'm already trying to explain to you here: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/discussions/686

Your service definition is wrong. According to your request document, what you need is the following:

```py
class SomeService(ServiceBase):
    __tns__ = 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound'

    @rpc(sObject)
    def MyMethod(ctx, mymethodparam):
        print(mymethodparam)
```

As for the error you are getting, it's actually pretty clear:

```
QName value '{urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com}Lead' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition
```

You need to have an object named "Lead" in the "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" namespace.

The following fragment implies that this is a polymorphic request:

```xml
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Lead" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
```

To parse polymorphic requests, you first need to enable them by passing `polymorphic=True` to your inbound protocol instantiation.

Then, you need to define all possible types that your system will accept.

In this case, you need at least the definition for the `Lead` object.

```
class SObjectType(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com'
    __type_name__ = 'sObject'
    Id = String
    Company_ID__C = Integer64
    Company_Size_Text__c = Unicode


class Lead(SObjectType):
    __namespace__ = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

    lead_field = Unicode

    # (...)
    # any additional fields that the lead object might have
```

As far as I remember, for a type to register as subclass, it must have at least one field of its own in its definition (this could be a bug or a feature, depending who you ask)

So if the Lead object has no additional fields, you need to have at least one field (called lead_field in this case) in its definition anyway. It's harmless as long as your code doesn't use it. However, if you already have additional fields in the Lead definition, you don't have to have it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Made the expected changes, but I am still getting an error.
`
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap11env:Body><soap11env:Fault><faultcode>soap11env:Client.ResourceNotFound</faultcode><faultstring>Requested resource '{http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound}notifications' not found</faultstring><faultactor></faultactor></soap11env:Fault></soap11env:Body></soap11env:Envelope>%
`

Comment: soap11env:Client.ResourceNotFound</faultcode><faultstring>Requested resource '{http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound}notifications' not found

Answer (score 1):

Worked! This is the final solution.

```
NS_C = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

class sObjectType(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = NS_C
    Id = Unicode
    Company_ID__C = Integer64
    Company_Size_Text__c = String

class Lead(sObjectType):
    lead_field = Unicode
     
class NotificationType(ComplexModel):
    Id = Unicode
    sObject = sObjectType

NS_B = "http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"

class OutboundMessagingService(ServiceBase):
    __namespace__ = NS_B
    @srpc(Unicode, NotificationType, sObjectType, _returns=notificationsResponseReturn)
    def notifications(tctx, Notification, sObject):
##. Do things here. 
application = Application([OutboundMessagingService], 
                            tns='http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound',
                            in_protocol=Soap11(),
                            out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)
```

Thanks Burak!